proper way to include internal and external data in custom R package
I'm creating an R package that has some included datasets that I both want to export for the user to use and to use internally in the package's function.
For example, let's say I create a dataset called measurements like this:
measurements <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), value = runif(10))
usethis::use_data(measurements, overwrite = TRUE)

That allows the measurements dataframe to be accessible externally to the user just by referencing measurements.
Now, I also want to write a package function that uses the same data frame internally:
#' fn_docalc
#' 
#' @param x Value to multiply by
#' 
#' @return Measurements dataframe multiplied by x
#' @export

fn_docalc <- function(x){
measurements$value <- measurements$value * x
measurements
}

This works fine, but the one case where it fails is if the user loads the package, and also happens to create their own variable called measurements in the global environment.  If that occurs, then fn_docalc operates on that new global variable instead of on the package's variable.  How can I properly write the function/package to always reference the internal measurements variable when fn_docalc is called even if a different global version of measurements exists?

I would guess you use the name of your package to namespace it to disambiguate where it comes from. mypackage::measurements ;

Did you verify this is a problem when you actually install the package? Or did you only test with something like devtools::load_all? Packages should create their own namespace and lexical scoping should resolve variables in their own name space before looking in the global environment.

@NirGraham thanks for that suggestion - I'll try that out

@MrFlick I verified this works once installed also (and with load_all). Ofc, my use case is more complex (and I discovered it in production/after package install), but I added the above exact example to my package, installed it and tried what I mentioned on a fresh session. Indeed if I make a global measurements var with different data, fn_docalc operates on THAT variable instead of the package's internal one.

@NirGraham I did some testing and I think your solution is best if you want to contribute it as an answer.  For more detail, I slightly changed fn_docalc to first create tmp <- myPkgName::measurements and then I operated on and returned tmp.  Also, my actual use case was using get("measurements") (because I needed to use the string of the variable name).  The proper fix to that was changing it to get("measurements", pos = "package:myPkgName").  Thanks!

Id be fine with you providing a self-answer; you could have your use case of get("measurements", pos = "package:myPkgName") which I didnt mention.

You used usethis::use_data(measurements, overwrite = TRUE); this put your dataset in the data subdirectory.  It has somewhat weird semantics.
If you have LazyData: true in your DESCRIPTION file, then the data object is put into the exports from the package, but it is not in the internal environment that functions use.  In that case your functions will need the myPkgname:: prefix.
If you don't have that LazyData: line, or set it to false, then the data is not visible at all until you call the data() function, which by default loads it into the global environment.
For your use case, where you want the data available both to users and to your own functions, neither of these makes sense.  You want the dataset visible in both environments.
To get it into the internal environment, you create it in one of your .R files in the R directory.  For your sample data, just put
measurements <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), value = runif(10))

in one of those files.  For a larger dataset you might want to store it in a compressed format somewhere (e.g. in inst/extdata), and have your .R file read it in at package install time.
To also get it into the exports, you specify it in your NAMESPACE file, or let Roxygen do that for you, by using @export in the .R file.

Thanks for taking a look.  This looks great so far.  I updated my git repo to include a second dataset (measurements2) and a second function that uses that (fn_docalc2).  I tested it and it works as I expect.  Funny thing - I didn't explicitly @export measurements2 yet it still is accessible to the user after attaching the package.  I'll test this in my production case now.

In my previous commit, i realized that check()/document() was skipping NAMESPACE because it was not generated by roxygen and that somehow caused measurements2 to be exported even though I didn't explicitly use @export in its R file. With that fixed the @export command works as expected. I also realized in my production set up that I still had the "myDataset" string after the roxygen section of each myDataset.R file, which was causing document() errors. With this solution, those files should only have the object definition after the roxygen section.  Thx for the help again.

With the help of @NirGraham, it seems you have to/should explicitly define the namespace of the data being referenced.  In the above example, the following function definition fixed the issue:
fn_docalc <- function(x){
tmp <- myPkgName::measurements
tmp$value <- tmp$value * x
tmp
}

Further, my actual use case was using the get() function instead of directly referencing the variable.  The equivalent in this case would be tmp <- get("measurements").  The fix to that was to include the pos argument like: tmp <- get("measurements", pos = "package:myPkgName")

also... this eliminates the need to declare utils::globalVariables(c("measurements")) elsewhere in the code so that check() won't complain about 'no visible binding for global variable'

Ahh, you didn't mention you were using utils::globalVariables in your original question. This makes a lot more sense now.

Thanks @user2554330, but my example above shows otherwise.  The function was using the variable in the global environment first and adding the package name fixed it.  Is there some other way I need to be properly defining internal package data that you know of?

@user2554330 that's exactly what I did... installed the package, attached it, and ran it with a bad measurements global variable.  I didn't source the function and it didn't appear as its own copy in the global env.  I'll definitely make a simple package and share it because I do believe including the package name is not optimal - otherwise it would explicitly be mentioned in Hadley's documentation (https://r-pkgs.org/).

@user2554330 here's a link to a full package... the readme has all the steps to recreate the issue.  thanks for checking it out. https://github.com/joeramirez/pkgDataTest

Sorry, my mistake.  I didn't notice that you had put it in the data directory. The rules for data are a little weird:  they depend on the LazyData: option in the DESCRIPTION file.  I think you have LazyData: true, in which case data objects are visible outside the package, and not inside, as you found.  I'll expand in an answer.
